# How to Store and Remove multiple attributes in session at one shot (Struts 2)?

Tags: struts2

Currently we can set attributes like this

```
request.getSession().setAttribute(groupName, groupName);
request.getSession().setAttribute(groupCode, groupCode);
```

but how can we set all of them together in one attempt and remove at one attempt ?

Edit : Thank You all, I got it working! i just created a inner class and used it to store and remove all attributes.

Eg :

```
public InnerClass {
         String data1;
         String data2;
         public InnerClass(String data1,String data2) {
         this.data1 = data1;
         this.data2 = data2;
       }
    }

//Set Attribute here
request.getSession().setAttribute("objectName",new InnerClas(data1,data2));

//Remove Attribute here
request.getSession.removeAttribute("objectName");
```

Comment: set them as object and remove them in same way..just use a single bean class to handle all those attributes, but that is not a good approach, use session to store only required attributes

Comment: Can you do two things at once? No, you should have a parallel your mind.

Answer (score 2):

Bean

```
class Group {
    private Long   code;
    private String name;
    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
}
```

Write

```
Group group = new Group();
group.setCode(1);
group.setName("first group");
request.getSession().setAttribute("group", group);
```

Read

```
Group group = (Group) request.getSession().getAttribute("group");
System.out.println(group.getCode());
System.out.println(group.getName());
```

But you should access the session in a different way ([through SessionAware is the preferred](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html))